# Does Azure API Management support streaming?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Does Azure API Management supports streaming e.g. sending 10 GB payloads? It would be a REST API returning a JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is streamed by default unless you buffer it explicitly by using either [policy expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) (context.Request.Body, context.Response.Body), [transformation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#TransformationPolicies) that manipulate the body like json-to-xml or the content validation policies like the [validate-content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#validate-content) policy

Comment: Great to hear, do you know if this is mentioned in the documentation or is this is just an anticipated feature?

Comment: I am not aware of any documentation for that!

Comment: How would you know then? :)

Comment: I have been working on Azure APIM for almost 4 years :)